# Cordova/Phonegap: andorid keyboard moves window to the left

Tags: android, cordova, android-softkeyboard

I have a problem with Cordova 5.4. When the keyboard shows up, my view is moved up (as is expect), but it also do it to the left. It seems that Cordova try to put the inputs elements on the center of the screen. I only want to move the view up, not to the sides. anyone has this problem and has solved it?

I have the adjustResize, and the fullscreen is set to false.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: set overflow: hidden to the div/body

Comment: It continues moving to the left. If I add overflow: hidden to the div, it no longer moves up and to left.